# Getting time elapsed of an MP3.

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I've been following some tutorials and read up on similar threads here but as I'm using FXML, I am struggling to represent the same thing.

So, essentially I'm trying to get the elapsed time to update every second on my timeText.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this.

Below, you can see my code for my controller class. Bare in mind, I've created my own queue as well.

**Main**

```html
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Application.launch(Main.class, (java.lang.String[])null);
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("musicPlayer.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("FXML is Simple");
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("css.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```html
public class graphicalController implements Initializable 
{
    //GUI Decleration
    public Button centreButton;
    public Button backButton;
    public Button forwardButton;
    public ToggleButton muteToggle;
    public MenuItem loadFolder;
    public Text nameText;
    public Text albumText;
    public Text timeText;
    public Text artistText;
    public Slider timeSlider;
    public Slider volumeSlider;

    //Controller Decleration
    String absolutePath;
    SongQueue q = new SongQueue();
    MediaPlayer player;
    Status status;
    boolean isPlaying = false;
    boolean isMuted = false;
    boolean isPaused = false;
    private Duration duration;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
    {
        centreButton.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/Resources/Play_Button.png')");
        centreButton.setText("");

        backButton.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/Resources/Back_Button.png')");
        backButton.setText("");

        forwardButton.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/Resources/Forward_Button.png')");
        forwardButton.setText("");

        muteToggle.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/Resources/ToggleSound_Button.png')");
        muteToggle.setText("");

        nameText.setText("");
        albumText.setText("");
        artistText.setText("");
    }

    public void handlecentreButtonClick() {
        if(isPlaying)
        {
            player.pause();
            centreButton.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/Resources/Play_Button.png')");
            isPaused = true;
            isPlaying = false;
        }
        else if(!(q.isEmpty())) {
            if(isPaused)
            {
                player.play();
                centreButton.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/Resources/Pause_Button.png')");
            }
            else{
                String file = q.peek().fileName.toString();
                String path = absolutePath + "\\" + file; 
                Media song = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
                player = new MediaPlayer(song);
                player.setVolume(volumeSlider.getValue() / 100);
                player.play();
                centreButton.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/Resources/Pause_Button.png')");
            }
            isPlaying = true;
        }
        setSongText();
    }

    public void handleforwardButtonClick() {
        player.stop();
        Song currentSong = q.peek();
        q.push(currentSong);
        q.pop();
        String file = q.peek().fileName.toString();
        String path = absolutePath + "\\" + file; 
        Media song = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
        player = new MediaPlayer(song);
        if(isPlaying) {
            player.play();
        }
        setSongText();
    }

    public void handlebackButtonClick() {
        player.stop();
        File folder = new File(absolutePath);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        int listLength = listOfFiles.length; 
        for (int k = 0; k < listLength-1; k++) {
            Song currentSong = q.peek();
            q.push(currentSong);
            q.pop();
        }
        String file = q.peek().fileName.toString();
        String path = absolutePath + "\\" + file; 
        Media song = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
        player = new MediaPlayer(song);
        if(isPlaying) {
            player.play();
        }
        setSongText();
    }

    public void handleLoadButtonClick() {
        DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
        File selectedDirectory = directoryChooser.showDialog(null);
        absolutePath = selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath();
        String path = absolutePath;
        loadFilesFromFolder(path);
    }

    public void handleVolumeSlider() {
        try {
            player.setVolume(volumeSlider.getValue() / 100);
        } catch (Exception b) {}
    }

    public void handleVolumeMute() {
        try{
            if(isMuted)
            {
                player.setVolume(volumeSlider.getValue() / 100);
                isMuted = false;
            }
            else
            {
                player.setVolume(0);
                isMuted = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception a) {}
    }

    public void loadFilesFromFolder(String path) {
        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        while(!(q.isEmpty()))
        {
            try {Thread.sleep(500);}catch (Exception e){}
            Song j = q.pop();
        }
        int listLength = listOfFiles.length; 
        for (int k = 0; k < listLength; k++) {
            if (listOfFiles[k].isFile()) {
                String fileName = listOfFiles[k].getName();
                String fileNamePath = path + "\\" +fileName; 
                try {
                    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(fileNamePath));
                    ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
                    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
                    Parser parser = new Mp3Parser();
                    ParseContext parseCtx = new ParseContext();
                    parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseCtx);
                    input.close();
                    String songName = metadata.get("title");
                    String artistName = metadata.get("xmpDM:artist");
                    String albumName = metadata.get("xmpDM:genre");
                    int id = k + 1;
                    Song newSong = new Song(id, fileName, songName, artistName, albumName);
                    q.push(newSong);
                    setSongText();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TikaException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }       
        } 
    }

    public void setSongText() {
        // String file = q.peek().fileName.toString();
        // String song = q.peek().songName.toString();
        // String artist = q.peek().artistName.toString();
        // String album = q.peek().albumName.toString();
        try {
            String file = q.peek().fileName.toString();
            String path = absolutePath + "\\" + file; 
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
            ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
            Parser parser = new Mp3Parser();
            ParseContext parseCtx = new ParseContext();
            parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseCtx);
            input.close();
            String songName = metadata.get("title");
            String artistName = metadata.get("xmpDM:artist");
            String albumName = metadata.get("xmpDM:genre");
            nameText.setText(songName);
            albumText.setText(albumName);
            artistText.setText(artistName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TikaException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void updateValues() {
        if (timeText != null && timeSlider != null && duration != null) {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Duration currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
                        timeText.setText(formatTime(currentTime, duration));
                        timeSlider.setDisable(duration.isUnknown());
                        if (!timeSlider.isDisabled() && duration.greaterThan(Duration.ZERO) && !timeSlider.isValueChanging()) {
                            timeSlider.setValue(currentTime.divide(duration).toMillis() * 100.0);
                        }

                    }
                });
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just bind the label's text to the media player's [current time property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#currentTimeProperty).

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look when I get home.

Comment: I've got it working with system out print. I will make my own answer to this after I get the entire slider working with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to updating the time every second for the elapsed time, I used a thread which looped every second to detect this change. Below you can see the code I used for this:

```
/**
     * Program thread: Run
     * Description: Cycles every second (998 Milliseconds) to detect a change in time for song. Values on GUI are updated accordinly. 
     */    
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true)
                {
                    if(isPlaying) {
                        currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
                        totalTime = player.getMedia().getDuration();

                        updateTimeValues();
                        updateTimeSlider();

                        if(totalTimeText.equals(currentTimeText))
                        {
                            if(isLooping) {
                                handlecentreButtonClick();
                            }
                            else {
                                handleforwardButtonClick();
                            }
                        }

                        try {Thread.sleep(498); }catch (Exception e){}
                    }
                    try {Thread.sleep(500);if(isDragging) {isDragging=false;}}catch (Exception e){}
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

I have now finished my project. You can view it by downloading the entire project, and it's source code, from my [BitBucket Account](https://bitbucket.org/Jetrise/comsci-public-project/downloads/).